# Google Analitycs and Woopra page views disproportion

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm currently using both Woopra and Google Analytics (GA) to track customers on my page. I've added custom Google Tag Manager (GTM) code to the site header as well as custom Woopra config script.

Then I've created Tags: one for GA Page View, second for Woopra Page View (woopra.track()). Both tags are triggered on All pages.

I've connected Woopra tracker to fire after GA tracker.

But still, both analytics are off. During the day, it can be up to 200 page views difference (GA: 600, Woopra: 400).

What's causing this problem?

Comment: You had two distinct questions here, one of which was off -topic. I removed that one so your question so it meets our site's criteria and can remain open.

Comment: The easy privacy list for Ad Block Plus would block Google Tag Manager, Google Analytics, and Woopra whether used together, or separately:  https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easyprivacy.txt

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic question. @StephenOstermiller - I get it, but it doesn't matter - the page views are different, and if the EasyList block woopra & GA the page views should still be 1:1

Comment: There may be some other commonly used list that blocks Woopra but allows GA and Google Tag Manager.   Seems unlikely though.

Comment: Knowing nothing about Woopra, the first thing I would check would be bot traffic. Do you have "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" checked on the GA View Settings admin page? Your discrepancy is very large but if Woopra has default filtering, and GA's was not enabled, it could account for at least some of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted Woopra support - they suggest that a small disproportion should not be the issue (https://docs.woopra.com/docs/why-are-my-stats-different-on-woopra-than-on-google-analytics).

I've found out that Webflow (our cms) can have issues with Google Tag Manager (if you enable it from the Webflow dashboard) so I've implemented my own Google Tag Manager code inside the page body.

I've also connected the Woopra tag to fire only after the Google Analitycs tag.

**Right now (two weeks in) difference is acceptable - around 100 page views difference / week.**